# Loading Array into TableView xCode

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, uitableview

Hey guys I'm new to Swift and iOS programming in general and am trying to create my first app. I am currently trying to load an array into a table view but the array isn't loaded. I'm not really sure how to check but I've been following this youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pR6dR-vVZeY , for the most part and adapting it to fit mine. I'm not getting any errors either. This is my code.
import UIKit

```
class routineTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var routines = [Routine]();



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var routines: [Routine] = [];
        var phatRoutine = Routine(nameOfRoutinex: "PHAT by Layne Norton", typeOfRoutinex: "Mixed");
        routines.append(phatRoutine)
        var smolovRoutine = Routine(nameOfRoutinex: "Smolov", typeOfRoutinex: "Strength");
        routines.append(smolovRoutine)

        for Routine in routines {
            println(Routine.nameOfRoutine);

        }

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
        // Return the number of sections.
        return 0
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return routines.count;
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var Cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell;
        Cell.textLabel?.text = routines[indexPath.row].nameOfRoutine;
        return Cell;

    }
}
```

I'm checking that  I am really adding the elements to the routine with the for loop and it says that I am. Not really sure where to go from here. Here is also my storyboard which I am also not sure is entirely correct.

Thank you for the help guys.

Answer (score 0):

Cells in UITableView are organized in groups called *sections*, as you tell the table it has no section it doesn't display any cell. Set the section count to one:

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1
}
```

Comment: Tried that, still nothing appears

Comment: Make sure your view controller is set as the `delegate` and `dataSource` of the tableView. If you use Interface Builder you can check this in the Connection inspector.

Comment: Yep, this is most probably it.

Comment: Please close issue or state you still haven't resolved it so the community can assist if needed.